# Kotlin Gradle Cucumber: Undefined Step

Tags: automation, cucumber

I am building a selenium automation project using cucumber and kotlin, but after I have set up the skeleton. The steps can't be identified by cucumber. I mainly call gradle cucumber on terminal to begin the test.

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.21'
    id "com.github.spacialcircumstances.gradle-cucumber-reporting" version "0.1.7"
}

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java8:4.7.1'
    testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-junit:4.3.1'
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.141.59'
    testImplementation 'no.tornado:tornadofx:1.7.17'

}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

configurations {
    cucumberRuntime {
        extendsFrom testImplementation
    }
}

task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--plugin', 'json:test_reports/' + getDate() + '_automation_test_result.json', '--glue', 'src/test/kotlin/steps', 'src/test/resources/feature']
        }
    }
}

cucumberReports {
    outputDir = file('test_reports/' + getDate()+ '_html')
    buildId = '0'
    reports = files('test_reports/' + getDate() + '_automation_test_result.json', 'test_reports/cucumber-json.json')
}


static def getDate() {
    def date = new Date()
    def formattedDate = date.format('yyyy-MM-dd')
    return formattedDate
}
```

Below is the structure:
[This is the folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqHi7.png)
Below is the result:

```
 Task :cucumber
Sep 18, 2019 5:27:40 PM cucumber.api.cli.Main run
WARNING: You are using deprecated Main class. Please use io.cucumber.core.cli.Main

Undefined scenarios:
src/test/resources/feature/test.feature:15 # Input something in the search bar
src/test/resources/feature/test.feature:16 # Input something in the search bar
src/test/resources/feature/test.feature:25 # Change to different sub-page
src/test/resources/feature/test.feature:26 # Change to different sub-page
src/test/resources/feature/test.feature:27 # Change to different sub-page
src/test/resources/feature/test.feature:28 # Change to different sub-page

6 Scenarios (6 undefined)
30 Steps (30 undefined)
0m0.100s


You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

Given("I have logged in as a super admin", () -> {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
});

Given("I have navigated to CRM", () -> {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
});

Given("I have clicked the client button on the navigation bar", () -> {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
});

When("I input {string} in the search bar", (String string) -> {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
});

Then("the search result should contain {string}", (String string) -> {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
});

Given("I have navigated to the home page on CRM", () -> {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
});

When("I click the {string} on the navigation bar", (String string) -> {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
});

Then("I should be brought to different page", () -> {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
});


BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
4 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 3 up-to-date
```

I can navigate to the step file when I ctrl+click on the implemented Given or When steps. It seems it can't find the steps definition when it runs. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Your glue `src/test/kotlin/steps` should be a package name, so just `steps`.

Comment: seems there is no greater cucumber support for Kotlin Android.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact issue and the answer above is correct, but a bit unclear. (I removed everything else rather than leaving the resources folder in there too!)

This is the `task cucumber()` section of my `build.gradle` file:

```
task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestKotlin
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "io.cucumber.core.cli.Main"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
            args = ['--plugin', 'pretty', '--glue', 'hellocucumber', 'src/test/resources']
        }
    }
}
```

where `hellocucumber` is my package name, as outlined in [this example](https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/).

I hope it helps!